# igraph in r: get edge direction

Tags: r, plot, igraph

I would like to use different colors for "in" edges vs. "out" edges when plotting a directed graph in igraph, but I can't find a way to get the edges direction. If I have that info, I then might be able to set a E(g)$color attribute based on the type of direction, in the lines of what Answer 1 here: [How to set edge colors and vertex spacing with R / igraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31418599/how-to-set-edge-colors-and-vertex-spacing-with-r-igraph) suggests for color-by-weight:

```
E(g)$color[E(g)$weight == 8] <- 'green'
E(g)$lty[E(g)$weight == 8] <- 1
E(g)$color[E(g)$weight == 3] <- 'green'
E(g)$lty[E(g)$weight == 3] <- 2
```

Thanks for any help or suggestions.

Comment: Any directed edge is both, an outgoing edge and an incoming edge, just for different nodes. Unless there is a subset of unconnected nodes in your graph for which you would like to apply this coloring scheme, I fail to see how that would work.

Comment: Right. Sorry about it: I'm afraid I got so much obssed by a specific couple of vertices that I lost track of the general point of view. Thanks.

Comment: No worries, we all have those days. Are those nodes unconnected? If they are, then amend your question and we will figure out an answer.

Comment: No, no unconnected nodes in the graph, but thanks again for your replies.